# Left join data frames but attach data after specific column?

Tags: r

I have two data frames that I want to left join, but I want the output to show the "joined" data after a specific column in the original data frame.

Here's an example:

**DF1:**

| Label | Price | Units |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | $5 | 10 |
| B | $6 | 15 |

**DF2:**

| Label | Color |
| --- | --- |
| A | Blue |
| B | Red |

**Desired Output:**

| Label | Price | Color | Units |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | $5 | Blue | 10 |
| B | $6 | Red | 15 |

Such that "Color" is added in the middle of the original data frame and not at the end.

All I have is:

```
DF_1 <- DF_1 %>%
left_join(DF_2, by="Label")
```

Answer (score 2):

After joining, you could use `select` to rearrange:

```
DF_1 <- DF_1 %>%
  left_join(DF_2, by="Label") %>%
  select(everything(), Units)
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to `select` is [`relocate`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/relocate.html), which allows a different way of moving columns around.

```r
library(dplyr)
left_join(DF1, DF2, by = "Label") %>%
  relocate(Color, .after = Price)
#   Label Price Color Units
# 1     A    $5  Blue    10
# 2     B    $6   Red    15
```